# Background events are not rendered when created by a Bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm having a slight problem with adding background events to FullCalendar through a Bootstrap modal.

I'm able to render the background event with a simple event data like this ([working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TokerX/9ovutfop/)):

```
var eventData = {
    start: '2016-10-01',
    end: '2016-10-04',
    rendering: 'background',
    color: '#ff9f89'
};
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);`
```

I'm also able to do this using a prompt for the title and an additional rule based on the title ([working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TokerX/h99afqub/)):

```
select: function(start, end) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    var eventData;
    if (title) {
        if (title === "holiday"){
            eventData = {
                start: start,
                end: end,
                rendering: 'background',
                color: '#ff9f89'
            };
        }
        else{
            eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end
            };
        }
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

The following code should also work ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TokerX/m7eqvpbg/)), but it doesn't. Adding a regular event through the modal isn't a problem, but whenever it's a background event nothing happens. Removing `rendering: 'background',` from the equation and it works, so the problem lies in that line for some reason.

But why would the background event behave differently than a normal event through the modal, whenever they work perfectly fine outside the initialisation or the calendar and with select?

```
select: function(start, end) {
    $('#calendarModal').modal('show');
    $('#calendarModal #startTime').val(start);
    $('#calendarModal #endTime').val(end);
}

// ...

$('#calendarModal').on('click', '#save', function(){
    var title = $('#calendarModal #title').val();
    var start = new Date($('#calendarModal #startTime').val());
    var end = new Date($('#calendarModal #endTime').val());
    var eventData;
    if (title){
        if (title === "holiday"){
            eventData = {
                start: start,
                end: end,
                rendering: 'background',
                color: '#ff9f89'
            };
        }
        else{
            eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end
            };
        }
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    $('#calendarModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It seems to be working correctly and your fiddle is working correctly. Are you using `agendaWeek`? From the docs _Background events that are timed will only be rendered on the time slots in agenda view. Background events that are all-day will only be rendered in month view or the all-day slots of agenda view._

Comment: @milz Whenever you type in "holiday" it should create a background event. With the modal it does create it on the agenda views, but not on the month view, whereas with the prompt it does create them on the month view as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you're having has to do with dates and the `allDay` parameter. The [`Background event`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/) documentation states the following:

> Background events that are **timed** will only be rendered on the time slots in agenda view. Background events that are **all-day** will only be rendered in month view or the all-day slots of agenda view.

So, what you should do is to check which view is being used and apply the `allDay` parameter correctly. Update the save function to this:

```
$('#calendarModal').on('click', '#save', function(){
    var title = $('#calendarModal #title').val();
    var start = moment($('#calendarModal #startTime').val());
    var end = moment($('#calendarModal #endTime').val());
    var eventData;

    // Get the current used view and set a default value to allDay
    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getView' ),
        allDay = false;

    // If the view is month, set allDay to true
    if (view.name === 'month') {
        allDay = true;
    }

    if (title){
        // When setting the event data, be sure to send the `allDay` param
        if (title === "holiday"){
            eventData = {
                start: start,
                end: end,
                rendering: 'background',
                color: '#ff9f89',
                allDay: allDay
            };
        }
        else{
            eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay
            };
        }
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    $('#calendarModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Here's the [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/m7eqvpbg/1/).

---

As a side note, the difference between the second and third fiddles is not just the bootstrap modal. On the second fiddle, you're using the `start` and `end` parameters as they are sent to the `select` method by FullCalendar.

On the third fiddle, you're getting a "date" from the inputs. I'm guessing here, but I would argue that's the reason it works when you use the prompt and doesn't when you use the modal.

However, as stated by the docs, the correct way is to sent the `allDay` parameter.

Comment: I don't know why it would have problems with the dates, because whatever it gets from the inputs is whatever originally was in start and end. And in the first example is has no problems accepting dates likes this: start: '2016-10-01'. 

So that's quite odd and confusing lol. And it kept me looking in the wrong directiong because the first 2 cases didn't require allDay.

Anyway, thank you for your help!